# Build & install node.js packages on offline AIX server

Tags: node.js, npm, build, compilation, aix

I installed Node.js on the offline AIX server. My problem is I couldn't install NPM packages on the server. I tried [npmbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmbox), [local-npm](https://github.com/local-npm/local-npm), [+](https://addyosmani.com/blog/using-npm-offline/) and [+](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/xinjinms/2016/08/25/use-local-npm-for-offline-npm-package-installation/) but the problem is still occurred. The problem is when I want to move some packages from Windows to AIX, like [node-oracledb](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb), I have to compile and rebuild package again on AIX but Internet needed. For solving this, I tried using [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) but I can't solve the problem.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you leave more information about how it's compiled and what the error log looks like? Or the packages are not fetched at all?